# Keras SimpleRNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to do Keras classification. I have 1043 words, represented as one-hot encoded matrices (20 letters long by 26 possibilities for each letter). Each one belongs to one of 19 different categories.

```
X.shape >>>>>> (1043, 20, 26)
```

```
Y.shape >>>>>> (1043, 19)
```

Here's my attempt to build the model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(50, input_shape=(20, 26), return_sequences=True))

model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(num_categories, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=20, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
```

This crashes saying: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_91 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1043, 19)`

I feel like I'm missing something obvious with the `input_shape` field, or is there some other config trick? I couldn't find any clear examples of this type of problem online either.

---

Update: I suspect I need to collapse the time slices down into one final answer, but I'm not sure how to do it. There's `TimeDistributed` which seems like it's on the right track but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `Flatten()` layer before adding your dense layer right after the output of the `RNN`. Because you have `return_sequences=True`, keras will emmit all hidden states from each timestep of the digested sequence resulting in an error while sending a 3 dimensional `(batch_size, timesteps, 50)` tensor into a dense layer.

```
>>> model = Sequential()
>>> model.add(SimpleRNN(50, input_shape=(20, 26), return_sequences=True))
>>> from keras.layers import Flatten
>>> model.add(Flatten())
>>> model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
>>> model.add(Dense(num_categories, activation='softmax'))
>>> model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
>>> model.fit(X, Y, epochs=20, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
1043/1043 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: -0.0735
```

However, I would recomend that instead of having `return_sequences` as True, you instead do not include that parameter and have it go straight into the dense layer. You are not doing a seq2seq problem - which is what `return_sequences` is mostly used for. Instead go with,

```
>>> model = Sequential()
>>> model.add(SimpleRNN(50, input_shape=(20, 26)))
>>> model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
>>> model.add(Dense(num_categories, activation='softmax'))
>>> model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
>>> model.fit(X, Y, epochs=20, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
Epoch 1/20
 910/1043 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: -0.3609
```

Final recommendations would be to use a different RNN model like a [`GRU`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_recurrent_unit) and also use an `Embedding` layer with pre-trained word vectors like those from [`GLoVE`](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). Not using pre-trained word embeddings will result in poor validation performance on small data sets. You can see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328516/what-embedding-layer-output-dim-is-really-needed-for-a-dictionary-of-just-10000/51328897#51328897) to help with using those embeddings. You may also want to check out [keras' functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) - it's better.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed <3

Comment: I've used embeddings before, but this project is about the way words sound rather than what they mean, so I'm skipping them this time. Thanks again!